# Generic function that returns different types based on the value of an argument

Tags: generics, rust, dependent-type

I have a struct which holds registers. I want my `read_register` function to return a `u8` for `Register::V0` and `Register::V1` but a `u16` for `Register::V2` and `Register::V3`. I'm not sure how to make the function generic over the return type. I'm getting the error `match arms have incompatible types` which does make sense because the types are different.

```
struct Registers {
    v0: u8,
    v1: u8,
    v2: u16,
    v3: u16,
}

enum Register {
    V0,
    V1,
    V2,
    V3,
}

impl Registers {
    fn read_register<T>(&self, register: Register) -> T {
        match register {
            Register::V0 => self.v0,
            Register::V1 => self.v1,
            Register::V2 => self.v2,
            Register::V3 => self.v3,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't.

Sorry, but there's just no way of doing this in Rust.  You'd need dependent types, which Rust doesn't have.  You could perhaps return an instance of an `enum` that just contains two variants (one for each type).  Or you could accept one callback for each "path" and let the caller decide how to resolve the problem.

```
fn read_register<FnU8, FnU16, R>(
    &self,
    register: Register,
    with_u8: FnU8,
    with_u16: FnU16,
) -> R
where
    FnU8: FnOnce(u8) -> R,
    FnU16: FnOnce(u16) -> R,
{
    match register {
        Register::V0 => with_u8(self.v0),
        Register::V1 => with_u8(self.v1),
        Register::V2 => with_u16(self.v2),
        Register::V3 => with_u16(self.v3),
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there was an answer but I'm fine with a return enum

Answer (score 0):

With [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) you can do a few things that would require path dependent types. In this case, like the following code:

```rust
pub struct Registers {
    pub v0: u8,
    pub v1: u8,
    pub v2: u16,
    pub v3: u16,
}
pub trait GetRegister {
    // this associated type is used to simulate path dependent types.
    type ReturnType;

    fn apply(&self, register: &Registers) -> Self::ReturnType;
}

pub struct GetRegister1;
impl GetRegister for GetRegister1 {
    type ReturnType = u8;

    fn apply(&self, register: &Registers) -> Self::ReturnType {
        register.v1
    }
}
pub struct GetRegister3;
impl GetRegister for GetRegister3 {
    type ReturnType = u16;

    fn apply(&self, register: &Registers) -> Self::ReturnType {
        register.v3
    }
}

impl Registers {
    pub fn fetch_register<A,B>(&self, fetcher: A) -> B
        where A : GetRegister + GetRegister<ReturnType = B> {
        fetcher.apply(self)
    }
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use serde_json::*;

    use super::*;

    #[test]
    pub fn fetch_registers() {
        let registers = Registers {
            v0: 1,
            v1: 2,
            v2: 3,
            v3: 4
        };

        let v1 : u8 = registers.fetch_register(GetRegister1);
        let v2 : u16 = registers.fetch_register(GetRegister3);
        assert_eq!(2, v1);
        assert_eq!(4, v2);
    }
}
```

(I'm uncertain if this method is a good solution for something this small, though).