# Dependending on what variant an enum is, how to return one of 2 different possible types inside it?

Tags: rust

Similar questions have been asked many times before, but the closest I have come to my case is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816946/generic-function-that-return-different-types-based-on-an-enum-input).

I'm trying to achieve something like this(although the match part is completely wrong).

```
struct A {
    a: i8,
    b: u8,
}

struct B {
    c: i16,
    d: u16,
}

enum select {
    type_a(A),
    type_b(B),
}

impl select {
    fn return_one<T>(&self) -> T {
        match self {
            type_a(a) => a,
            type_b(b) => b,
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, it has an extra caveat, where the values inside the enum can be either of two structs. Is there some generics magic that I'm overlooking? Maybe I should compare the types with `std::mem::discriminant()`? I would very much to avoid having 2 methods using `Option<T>`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `match` instead of calling `return_one`?

Comment: No, it's not possible, for exactly the same reason as in the question you linked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic function that return different types based on an enum input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43816946/generic-function-that-return-different-types-based-on-an-enum-input)

Comment: @APerson, that was the exact question I had linked in the beginning!! :)

Comment: Yes; there's really no other way to do exactly what you're asking for. The code in the current answer to this question may panic at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to craft something that does kind-of what you are asking for, but I would not recommend it.

```
pub struct A {
    a: i8,
    b: u8,
}

pub struct B {
    c: i16,
    d: u16,
}

enum Select {
    TypeA(A),
    TypeB(B),
}

trait FromSelect {
    fn from_select(sel: Select) -> Self;
}

impl FromSelect for A {
    fn from_select(select: Select) -> Self {
        match select {
            Select::TypeA(a) => a,
            _ => panic!("Tried to select B from A")
        }
    }
}

impl FromSelect for B {
    fn from_select(select: Select) -> Self {
        match select {
            Select::TypeB(b) => b,
            _ => panic!("Tried to select A from B")
        }
    }
}

impl Select {
    fn return_one<T: FromSelect>(self) -> T {
        FromSelect::from_select(self)
    }
}

fn main() {

    let s: Select = Select::TypeA(A { a: 5, b: 5 });

    let _aa = s.return_one::<A>();

    let s2: Select = Select::TypeA(A { a: 7, b: 7 });

    // This Panics
    let _bb = s2.return_one::<B>();

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8dfe66601342beee2344b99e0cf6ccde)

I say "Kind Of" because I could not define a `FromSelect` trait that did not consume the `Select` enum, for reasons I do not entirely understand.

Also, you said you don't want two different methods - I was only partially able to achieve that. In this solution there are two methods defined, but the caller does not need to know that as they are abstracted over using generics.

As you can see from the main function, you need to use "turbofish" syntax to specify at compile time the variant you want to get back (or you could annotate the variable you are putting it into) - but if you get that wrong the program panics. Worse, the compiler will not be able to warn you that you have gotten it wrong!

To me that negates whatever slight benefit you might get. On top of that there is quite a lot of boiler plate required.

Comment: Ah damn, tbh I was sorta expecting something along the lines of "yes, but no". Thank you so much for your answer though. I guess I'll just shift the burden onto the caller!