# How can I define a trait function that takes an argument by reference

Tags: rust

I came across this issue while experimenting with different ways to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61704402/dependending-on-what-variant-an-enum-is-how-to-return-one-of-2-different-possib/61706170#61706170).

I'm trying to define a trait which takes an argument by reference, and returns `Self`, like this:

```
struct X {}

trait CopyFrom {
    fn copy_from(&x: X) -> Self;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error[E0642]: patterns aren't allowed in functions without bodies
 --> src/main.rs:5:18
  |
5 |     fn copy_from(&x: X) -> Self;
  |                  ^^ pattern not allowed in function without body
```

If I take `x` by value it compiles fine (but that would consume the argument, which I don't want).

The Rust reference has this to say:

> The kinds of patterns for parameters is limited to one of the
>   following:
>
> - IDENTIFIER
> - mut IDENTIFIER
> - _
> - & IDENTIFIER
> - && IDENTIFIER
>
> Beginning in the 2018 edition, function or method parameter patterns
>   are no longer optional. Also, all irrefutable patterns are allowed as
>   long as there is a body. Without a body, the limitations listed above
>   are still in effect.

I was not able to find anything else that would explain why I can't define a trait function that takes an argument by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong syntax here — `&x: X` is a [reference pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html) that dereferences the argument of type `X`; in other words,

```
fn f(&x: X) {
    // ...
}
```

is equivalent to

```
fn f(x: X) {
    let &x = x;
}
```

which, in turn, means

```
fn f(x: X) {
    let x = *x;
}
```

Instead, you want to make the parameter itself a reference:

```
fn f(x: &X) { // take argument by reference
    // ...
}
```